# Рефакторинг контроллера в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Куда можно вынести код из контроллера, чтобы он не был таким жирным??
Какие решения есть для таких случаев?
Я так понимаю командная шина тут не подходит?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'widget' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
    }

    $namespace = !(array_key_exists($request['widget'],$this->config)) ?: $this->config[$request['widget']]['namespace'];

    if (!class_exists($namespace)) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Widget Not Found']);
    }

    $widget = new $namespace();

    if(!($widget instanceof WidgetFieldInterface)) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Widget Not Implement WidgetFieldInterface']);
    }

    return response()->json($widget->getField());
}
```

Comment: Это ещё не **жирный.**

Comment: Я просто не все  выложил.Мне очень не нравятся эти условности, которые хочется куда-то вынести(не знаю куда).И второй момент, проверка на принадлежность к интерфесу, он явно находится не там.Вот хотел совета, от опытных людей

Comment: Ну почему, можно и через нее , или сделать папочку Services в ней классы называть WidgetByNamspaceService

Answer (score 0):

Вместо валидатора в контроллере можешь использовать Form Request https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation

Остальное можешь в сервисы вынести

Comment: Я изначально делал через Form Request.Но там проблема появилась.Когда с клиента отправляю запрос через аякс, и когда ошибка в валидаци, мне в консоль выселает код ошибки и все такое, не мог исправить этот момент, и выловить эту ошибку, чтобы он не показывался.Пришлось все менять

Comment: Имеешь ввиду кастомный ответ хотел сделать? В классе валидации можно же переопределить метод failedValidation. Что то типа такого `protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
 {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
 }`

Comment: Ты попал прямо в точку.Я нашел уже такую ошибку в одной теме, уже переделал.Хотя  я тут все переделал.

Comment: Я тут пытаюсь создать  аналог Widget страницы, как в  WP. Нужно было как-то получать тип виджета. Создать его и сохранить.И я пытался это все держать в базе.Но вышло очень грубо.Сейчас все перекинул в config/widget.php. Там есть массив widget. Создаем TextWidget  и описываем там же  его поля.И когда нужно создать виджет, я дергаю этот файл.Без всяких  $widget = new $namespace();. Все вышло оболдено.Но еще можно отрефакторить. Над этим занят сейчас. http://prntscr.com/iiw966